# Function for generating LaTeX tables from R summaries (using RPy)

Tags: python, r, rpy2, xtable, stargazer

I am trying to obtain a latex table with the summary of a `lme4.lmer()` run.

There are a number of R packages which claim to do this. However, in my experience none of them could. Here is a run-down:

- **xtable** - doesn't seem to take my input, neither the linear model nor the summary. See [my example](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.github.com/TheChymera/7396334/raw/2198825d982b045f6d2107182a355e9d3b481495/nlme-aov).
- **stargazer** -  performed almost what I wanted it to do. Can process the liner model (`lme4.lmer()`) but not the summary (`base.summary(lme4.lmer())`). See [this notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.github.com/TheChymera/7445877/raw/ec1f0125594dce2bf7557d2c2c0982f1b1e9c903/stargazer).
- **texreg** - performed almost what I wanted it to do. Can process the liner model (`lme4.lmer()`) but not the summary (`base.summary(lme4.lmer())`). See [the relevant notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.github.com/TheChymera/7429986/raw/6b07e07cd1a982da7a9364aa1f196c15388f3afe/R-to-LaTeX).

Comment: We will need some examples. Try taking your car to a mechanic and saying "it doesn't work". What is not working?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik my post specifies a full example of code including error messages for every single package.